# Problems with loading user profile with PyQGIS

Tags: python, qgis, pyqgis

Hi I have the following code for my startup.py script when starting QGIS3, that I want to check if a userprofile exists, and if not then to create and load it, but it seems like this process falls into some kind of a unstoppable loop, making it unpossible to use the application.

```
from qgis.core import * 
from PyQt5 import * 
import os import getpass
import qgis
defaultsti = QgsApplication.qgisSettingsDirPath() 
os.chdir(defaultsti)
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))
r = os.getcwd() 
a = QgsUserProfileManager(r).allProfiles() 
g = getpass.getuser()

if QgsUserProfileManager(r).profileExists(g): 
   import qgis
   qgis.core.QgsUserProfileManager(r).loadUserProfile(g)

else:
   import qgis
   import getpass
   g = getpass.getuser() 
   qgis.core.QgsUserProfileManager(r).createUserProfile(g) 
   QgsUserProfileManager(r).loadUserProfile(g)
```

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you question because that help me for something.
I modified your code a little to exploit it.

```
from qgis.core import * 
from PyQt5 import * 
import os 
import getpass

defaultsti = QgsApplication.qgisSettingsDirPath() #path to current profile
os.chdir(defaultsti)
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))
r = os.getcwd() 
a = QgsUserProfileManager(r).allProfiles() #get all profiles in a list
g = getpass.getuser()

if QgsUserProfileManager(r).profileExists(g): 
   QgsUserProfileManager(r).loadUserProfile(g) #load profile if it exists
else:
   QgsUserProfileManager(r).createUserProfile(g) #create profile if doesn't exist
   QgsUserProfileManager(r).loadUserProfile(g) #then load it
```

Comment: Can you please provide further information and describe what the problem was and how you fixed it

Comment: For the libraries, we see that in original script we import many times the same libraries. This is unnecessary. Moreover he calls two libraries in the same line "import os import getpass" and that's the error. After when you call "from qgis.core import *" that is to import all functions and don't have to write it again. QgsUserProfileManager for exemple is a class from qgis.core